# Is it right to say "You are waiting me on a mistake"

Tags: expressions, usage

If there's some person (e.g., in your work space) who is waiting on you to make a mistake then to give you a warning or something, is it right to tell him:

> "You're waiting me on a mistake"?

How can I tell him that the right way?

This person is jealous of me and trying to catch me out on something so he fire me out of the job.

Comment: If I made some mistake and he came to me and gave me the warning then I told him that sentence wrong as well, that would be too many mistakes and he will absolutely fire me :D

Comment: waiting _for;_ waiting on is what waiters do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to describe someone who is doing this is to say:

> You are waiting for me to make a mistake.

"Waiting on me" is incorrect here, and so is "waiting me". "You are waiting for a mistake" would also be grammatically correct, but means they are waiting for anyone to make a mistake, not just you.

"waiting on" correctly refers a waiter in a restaurant who is serving someone, which is completely different meaning of "waiting. However "waiting on" is used frequently enough instead of "waiting for" that it is probably acceptable, especially in North America.